# Drawing tools for scientific papers

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing, sketching

Hello I would you to propose me a program which can be used to make figures on scientific papers. An example of a figure that I want to create is of a body (2d) with forces on it, or figures with strings, simple masses in 2D. Thank you for your time, if someone want more information please tell me.
These are similar to the figures that I want to make.

[image: image 1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about *any* graphic application *could* create these.

The stumbling block is often a learning curve or difficulty due to an application's toolset.

I would suggest a *vector editor* for ease, but there will still be a learning curve.

[**Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/) is a free, open-source, vector editor.

[**Adobe Illustrator**](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) is a subscription based vector editor.

There are other vector editors out there. Such as [**Sketch**](https://www.sketch.com/) or [**CorelDraw**](https://www.coreldraw.com/en/), which lie somewhere between the two above in terms of cost.

However, if you need the dimensioning and labels you'll need to look at more drafting related applications and CAD software such as AutoCad or SolidWorks. Solidworks has some free 2D CAD tools.

How useful any of this is greatly depends upon your dedication to "do it yourself". In some instances it may be more efficient to merely hire someone to create the figures you need based upon your sketches. Learning a software product to the proficiency one desires can be difficult at times.

Comment: Thank you for your response I will take a further look at Inkscape!

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a program with pre-made human figures I'd suggest trying [Poser](http://poser.smithmicro.com/). It is a 3D program though, but you could easily render images out to 2D silhouettes. It's the only program I know where you can easily manipulate or pose pre-made figures without having to first create them yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly Poser is not what I am searching. I added some links to my question to be more precise.

Comment: @2island Got it now - when you said figures I assumed you meant human figures.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I will answer my question. The best and simplest program to use is COREL DRAW. Thank you for you responses!