# Tools for drawing container terminals for scientific publications

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing, paper

For my scientific paper, I want to illustrate my problem in a visually appealing way with some sketches. Unfortunately, I was unable to find any web tools or apps that would allow me to draw figures such as the ones in [this paper [PDF]](https://www.hsu-hh.de/bp/wp-content/uploads/sites/829/2022/06/2019_EJOR_2.pdf) (figure 1 and figure 2)

I appreciate your time and interest in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing tools for scientific papers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/drawing-tools-for-scientific-papers)

Comment: what do you use now?

Comment: Maybe try Figma. I'm pretty sure you could use it for such drawings.  If you need more complexity however, you might need a fully fledged vector image editor like Inkscape (free and Open Source), or Illustrator (not free). But you need a computer install/run them on These aren't web apps.

Comment: Yes Figma should probably work, if you need a web app specifically.